# Error Synchronous XMLHttpRequest en función load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, ajax

bueno miren tengo algo más o menos así:

```
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/2.1.1.min.js"></script><script>function Navigator(pageName, parameters = ""){
            $( "#body" ).html('<center><img src="/images/loading.gif"/></center>');
            $( "#body" ).load( "/page/"+pageName, { "data":parameters }, 
              function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
              //cargado!
              });
          }
        </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/tipsy.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/tipsy.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(function() {
        $("[title]").tipsy({fade: true, gravity: $.fn.tipsy.autoNS});
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body oncontextmenu='return false'>
      <div id="content">
        <header>....</header>

        <nav><ul> <li onclick="Navigator('news');"></li> ... </ul></nav>
        <div id="body"> Div donde se cargan las páginas al dar click en algun <li> del nav .......
        </div>
      </div> <div id="footer">.... <a href="#" title="Tipsy working!">Tipsy hover</a></div>
```

Cuando doy en algún `li` Me carga bien la primera vez, y me aparece este mensaje:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check

Pero cuando intento dar click otra vez en algun `<li>` me aparece esto:

> Cannot read property 'html' of null
>       at Navigator (life:64)
>       at HTMLLIElement.onclick (VM1745 life:97)

Además... cuando se carga un contenido e intento usar en el mismo una funcion ya cargada en el  no carga dentro del `load`,me sale mensaje como este.

> is not defined.

¿Alguien me podría decir como solucionarlo por favor? Llevo 2 días sin dormir bien por tratar de solucionar esto :(

PD: Ya he intentado con document ready... window Load, etc

Comment: No me queda claro qué es lo que intentas hacer, aquí no hay ninguna llamada a $.ajax

Comment: El script de jQuery que tienes arriba en el header no está bien cerrado (tienes 'scrip' en vez de 'script'). Después tienes un link externo de CSS dentro del código html, cosa que no había visto en mi vida, quítalo de ahí y ponlo en el header para que cargue la hoja de estilos antes que el documento HTML. Y por ultimo tienes una etiqueta 'script' al final que no referencia ningún archivo externo :S.  Es muy confuso todo.